# How to add up value via function - PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a function that add up number to a given variable each time a button was click.

I have 4 buttons: farm, cave, house, casino
[image]

So what I am trying to achieve here is I need to send the random numbers generated by the buttons to a variable that will add up all of the SCORE on the "YOUR GOLD" section. So let's say I click the farm and the cave button so there will be 20 for the cave and 15 for farm for a total of 35 gold already.

Here's my form.php

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="gold">
        <form action="process-game.php" method="post" >
            YOUR GOLD: <input type="hidden" name="building" value="gold"/>
        </form>
    </div>


<div class="farm_form">
    <h2>Farm</h2>
    <form action="process-game.php" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="building" value="farm"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
    </form>
</div>


<div class="farm_form">
    <h2>Cave</h2>
    <form action="process-game.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="building" value="cave"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
    </form>
</div>


<div class="farm_form">
    <h2>House</h2>
    <form action="process-game.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="building" value="house"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
    </form>
</div>


<div class="farm_form">
    <h2>Casino</h2>
    <form action="process-game.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="building" value="casino"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
```

Here's my process.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['building'])){
        echo earn_gold();
    }

    function earn_gold(){
        if($_POST['building'] == "farm"){
            $gold = rand(10,20);
        }else if($_POST['building'] == "cave"){
            $gold = rand(5,10);
        }else if($_POST['building'] == "house"){
            $gold = rand(2,5);
        }else if($_POST['building'] == "casino"){
            $gold = rand(0,50);
        }
        return $gold;
    }


?>
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Basically I need the  echo earn_gold(); to add up all the numbers generated.

Comment: You *can* definitely achieve what you want using PHP. In order to do so, you will need to set up a `session` for this page (**and** store the score values into the `$_SESSION` array!!), so values would be added to the same counter again. **BUT**: I strongly recommend doing this type of user interaction on the browser directly, using JavaScript, possibly in connection with jQuery. Programming will be easier and the user experience will be better in the end ...

Comment: @cars10: is there a way you can show some demo? or demo codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need it, I guess you can do it with sessions.

```
if (isset($_POST['building'])) {
    // getting random gold 
    $earn_gold = earn_gold();
    // adding to session called "gold"
    $_SESSION['gold'] = (isset($_SESSION['gold']) ? $_SESSION['gold'] + $earn_gold : $earn_gold);
    // redirect back to process page
    header('Location: process.php');
    exit;
}
```

And then outputting it like so

```
<div id="gold">
    <form  method="post" >
        YOUR GOLD: <input type="hidden" name="building" value="gold"/> 
        <?php 
            // if set, outputting sessions "gold" value
            if (isset($_SESSION['gold'])) echo $_SESSION['gold']; 
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you start a session with session_start() at the beginning of "form.php"?

Comment: It works, how can i redirect it to the form page just to show the results after processing?

Comment: It still not redirecting mate.

Answer (score 1):

I know, you basically wanted a solution in PHP. Still, I could not resist showing you, how easy it would be doing the same in JavaScript/jQuery. Have a look at it or simply ignore it. It is up to you ... ;-)

```js
// define gold amounts for each button (min,max):
var finds={farm:[10,20],cave:[5,10],house:[2,5],casino:[0,50]}; 

$(function(){
 $(':submit').click(function(){ // for all submit buttons: bind the click event to a function ...
   var place=$(this).closest('div[id]').attr('id'); // get the id of the buttin's parent div
   var fnd=finds[place]; // get the min/max array for the current button
   with ($('#gold span')) // locate and use the <span> inside the div with id=gold
     text(parseFloat(text()) // get the current value of the span (convert to float)
          +fnd[0]+Math.ceil(Math.random()*(fnd[1]-fnd[0]))); // add the gold ...
 });
})
```

```css
div {display:inline-block; width: 120px; border:1px solid grey}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="farm_form" id="gold">
  <h2>Your Gold</h2><span>0</span>
</div><br>
<div class="farm_form" id="farm">
  <h2>Farm</h2><input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
</div>
<div class="farm_form" id="cave">
  <h2>Cave</h2><input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
</div>
<div class="farm_form" id="house">
  <h2>House</h2><input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
</div>
<div class="farm_form" id="casino">
  <h2>Casino</h2><input type="submit" value="Find Gold!"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user click on find gold then submit a form which will add the gold to the total result. For example if the user gets 3 gold then add the gold variable.

```
$totalGold = 0;

when user.click button then $totalgold +3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have one form element and use javascript to assign onclick events to each of the butons and may be use ajax to submit the form dynamically and display the results back on same page.